# How to log to a syslog server (udp 514) with python3?

Tags: python-3.x, logging, syslog

This is very much reduced code to demonstrate my issue. I want to redirect the logging to Syslog, port 514/UDP, because I am using multiprocessing, and then the serialization of the log messages is done by the server.

Note that I need a portable solution (to both Linux and Windows).

my best (failed) attempt is:

```
import functools
import logging
import logging.handlers
import multiprocessing as mp

my_logger = logging.getLogger('MyLogger')
handler = logging.handlers.SysLogHandler(address=('localhost', 514))
my_logger.addHandler(handler)
my_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

def _logger(name, level, msg, exc_info=None):
    my_logger.log(level, f'{msg}', exc_info=exc_info)


class ContextManager:
    def __init__(self):
        self.log = functools.partial(_logger, "init")

    def __enter__(self):
        self.log(logging.ERROR, f"entering...")
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        if exc_type:
            self.log(logging.ERROR, f"Exception: {exc_val}", exc_info=(exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb))
        else:
            self.log(logging.DEBUG, f"no exception, peaceful end")


def main():
    with ContextManager() as ctx:
        ctx.log(logging.DEBUG, f"running in main")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

... but the output does not show up on the side of the Syslog server.

Things I checked/tried:

- Port 514/UDP is open (nmap)
- Syslog server listens on port (visual
  syslog server under windows 10)
- restarted system
- tried logging other stuff to the syslog server, and it receives messages

At this point, I run out of things that I could have done wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This works. Even changing small details like "127.0.0.1" vs. "localhost" makes it stop working.

```
import functools
import sys
import logging
from logging import config

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(module)s P%(process)d T%(thread)d %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'stdout': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'stream': sys.stdout,
            'formatter': 'verbose',
        },
        'sys-logger6': {
            'class': 'logging.handlers.SysLogHandler',
            "address": ["127.0.0.1", 514],
            'facility': "local6",
            'formatter': 'verbose',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'my-logger': {
            'handlers': ['sys-logger6', 'stdout'],
            'level': logging.DEBUG,
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}

config.dictConfig(LOGGING)

my_logger = logging.getLogger('my-logger')


def _logger(level, msg, exc_info=None):
    my_logger.log(level, f'{msg}', exc_info=exc_info)


class ContextManager:
    def __init__(self):
        self.log = functools.partial(_logger, "init")

    def __enter__(self):
        self.log(logging.ERROR, f"entering...")
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        if exc_type:
            self.log(logging.ERROR, f"Exception: {exc_val}", exc_info=(exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb))
        else:
            self.log(logging.DEBUG, f"no exception, peaceful end")


def main():
    with ContextManager() as ctx:
        ctx.log(logging.INFO, f"running in main")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```